# Python web scraping how to loop all pages/next page

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

Can someone help me how to loop the next page have tried all the solutions on here but cant seem to get it to work.

```
import pandas as pd
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None  # default='warn'  # to suppress "false positive" warnings
import datetime as dt
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time



def getPage(url):
    attempt = 1
    while True:
        response = requests.get(url)
        if response.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
            return response.content
        else:
            time.sleep(0.5)
            attempt += 1
            if attempt > 3:
                print("Data could not be requested for url:  ", url, "  after  ", attempt, "  attempts")
                return None



if __name__ == '__main__':


    url = "https://www.opic.com/upphandlingar/"

    data_df = pd.DataFrame()  # all data from the websites is saved to this data frame
    # get data
    try:
        markup = getPage(url).decode('utf-8')
    except:
        markup = getPage(url)


    if markup is None:
        print("Nothing was found. Value of 'markup' is 'None'.")
        sys.exit()

    soup = BeautifulSoup(markup, 'lxml')

    containers = soup.findAll("a", {"class": "ListItem"})
    for container in containers:
        upplagtdatum = container.div.p.text.strip()
        titel = container.h3.text.strip()
        stad_kommun = container.span.text.strip()



        # ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        # Save data to data frame
        df = pd.DataFrame(data={'Upplagtdatum': [upplagtdatum], 'Titel': [titel], 'Stad Kommun': [stad_kommun]})
        data_df = pd.concat([data_df, df], sort=False)


    #   SAVE DATA

    # Save data frame to csv-file

    filePathName = "data_" + dt.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d') + ".csv"
    data_df.to_csv(filePathName, sep=';', index=False, encoding='utf-8')


    print(data_df)

import pandas as pd
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None  # default='warn'  # to suppress "false positive" warnings
import datetime as dt
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

def getPage(url):
    attempt = 1
    while True:
        response = requests.get(url)
        if response.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
            return response.content
        else:
            time.sleep(0.5)
            attempt += 1
            if attempt > 3:
                print("Data could not be requested for url:  ", url, "  after  ", attempt, "  attempts")
                return None

if __name__ == '__main__':

 url = "https://www.opic.com/upphandlingar/"

    data_df = pd.DataFrame()  # all data from the websites is saved to this data frame
    # get data
    try:
        markup = getPage(url).decode('utf-8')
    except:
        markup = getPage(url)


    if markup is None:
        print("Nothing was found. Value of 'markup' is 'None'.")
        sys.exit()

    soup = BeautifulSoup(markup, 'lxml')

    containers = soup.findAll("a", {"class": "ListItem"})
    for container in containers:
        upplagtdatum = container.div.p.text.strip()
        titel = container.h3.text.strip()
        stad_kommun = container.span.text.strip()

 # Save data to data frame
        df = pd.DataFrame(data={'Upplagtdatum': [upplagtdatum], 'Titel': [titel], 'Stad Kommun': [stad_kommun]})
        data_df = pd.concat([data_df, df], sort=False)

filePathName = "data_" + dt.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d') + ".csv"
    data_df.to_csv(filePathName, sep=';', index=False, encoding='utf-8')


    print(data_df)
```

Comment: Can you add some more info to your question? That way you can also properly format your code instead of posting it as plain text

Comment: Please format the code properly and describe specifically what you want to get and what you get instead. Include only the code necessary and sufficient for the question. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some changes in your code. Use this formatting you can achieve pagination.

```
import pandas as pd
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None  # default='warn'  # to suppress "false positive" warnings
import datetime as dt
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import sys

def getPage(url):
    attempt = 1
    while True:
        response = requests.get(url)
        if response.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
            return response.content
        else:
            time.sleep(0.5)
            attempt += 1
            if attempt > 3:
                print("Data could not be requested for url:  ", url, "  after  ", attempt, "  attempts")
                return None

def getData(markup):
    data_df = pd.DataFrame()  # all data from the websites is saved to this data frame
    soup = BeautifulSoup(markup, 'lxml')
    containers = soup.findAll("a", {"class": "ListItem"})
    for container in containers:
        upplagtdatum = container.div.p.text.strip()
        titel = container.h3.text.strip()
        stad_kommun = container.span.text.strip()

        # ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        # Save data to data frame
        df = pd.DataFrame(data={'Upplagtdatum': [upplagtdatum], 'Titel': [titel], 'Stad Kommun': [stad_kommun]})
        data_df = pd.concat([data_df, df], sort=False)

    #   SAVE DATA
    # Save data frame to csv-file
    filePathName = "data_" + dt.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d') + ".csv"
    data_df.to_csv(filePathName, sep=';', index=False, encoding='utf-8')
    print(data_df)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    results = 2871
    per_page = 20
    url = "https://www.opic.com/upphandlingar/?p={}"
    no_of_pages = int(results/per_page)
    for page_no in range(1,no_of_pages + 1):
        try:
            markup = getPage(url.format(page_no)).decode('utf-8')
        except:
            markup = getPage(url)

        if markup is None:
            print("Nothing was found. Value of 'markup' is 'None'.")
            sys.exit()
        else:
            getData(markup)
```

**Explanation**

- Each page has same template/page structure , so you need some function to extract the required  content
- Pagination, How next page is getting formed, here if you see the URL **p=** param getting added in URL.
- How many pages ? It depends on how many results in total and how much per page .If you figure out just do the map and iterate over it

Have a look on code, update it if required.

Comment: when i try this code i get the error 
Data could not be requested for url:   https://www.opic.com/upphandlingar/?p=0   after   4   attempts
Data could not be requested for url:   https://www.opic.com/upphandlingar/?p={}   after   4   attempts
Nothing was found. Value of 'markup' is 'None'.

Comment: The error due to there is no 0 th page. It starts from index 1. I change code a bit. Ie. https://www.opic.com/upphandlingar/?p=1 not from https://www.opic.com/upphandlingar/?p=0. Code changed here  `for page_no in range(1,no_of_pages + 1)`

Comment: I got it to work, do you know why it only saves the last 23 results to the csv? it doesnt save all of the pages only one page. but I can see that it scrapes all of the pages

Comment: Seems you are writing the data on same file. Try to make it dynamic. If  you check in the code , i have initialized data frame in the getData function based on your code it will save multiple csv files. Or you can declare single csv file and append the data with that. Hope this will solve your issue, Dont forget to upvote:)

Comment: Im pretty new to coding, how do I make it to save the diffrent pages, sorry if im disturbing you..

Comment: No problem!  I have added simple example over [here](https://github.com/dhamodharanrk/stackoverflow/tree/master/CSV_Operations).

Comment: where do i put it in my code got abit messy when i tried to do it :/

Comment: use that as sample and try to build the code. Even you can refer this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56037089/how-to-scrape-multiple-webpages-without-overwriting-the-results) which has similar use case

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the website and the code you provided, I assume you want to extract the href attribute from all the ListItem (containers) that you get. You can simply get the href like this:
*(assuming you have BeautifulSoup4)*

```
    for container in containers:
        upplagtdatum = container.div.p.text.strip()
        titel = container.h3.text.strip()
        stad_kommun = container.span.text.strip()
        href = container.get('href')
```

You can then either use that href immediately, or you could save it in your DataFrame to loop through it later.

Comment: the thing I am trying to do is to scrape the other diffrent pages because i can scrape the first page, but cant seem to write a code that continues to scrape the other pages with the same info (  the next button )