# How to scrape multiple webpages without overwriting the results?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, xml-parsing, html-parsing

New to scraping and trying to scrape multiple webpages from Transfermarkt without overwriting the previous one.

Know that this question has been asked previously but I can't get it to work for this case.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import re
import pandas as pd
import itertools

headers = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0'}
df_headers = ['position_number' , 'position_description' , 'name' , 'dob' , 'nationality' , 'height' , 'foot' , 'joined' , 'signed_from' , 'contract_until']
urls = ['https://www.transfermarkt.com/fc-bayern-munich-u17/kader/verein/21058/saison_id/2018/plus/1', 'https://www.transfermarkt.com/fc-hennef-05-u17/kader/verein/48776/saison_id/2018/plus/1']

for url in urls:
    r = requests.get(url,  headers = headers)
    soup = bs(r.content, 'html.parser')


    position_number = [item.text for item in soup.select('.items .rn_nummer')]
    position_description = [item.text for item in soup.select('.items td:not([class])')]
    name = [item.text for item in soup.select('.hide-for-small .spielprofil_tooltip')]
    dob = [item.text for item in soup.select('.zentriert:nth-of-type(3):not([id])')]
    nationality = ['/'.join([i['title'] for i in item.select('[title]')]) for item in soup.select('.zentriert:nth-of-type(4):not([id])')]
    height = [item.text for item in soup.select('.zentriert:nth-of-type(5):not([id])')]
    foot = [item.text for item in soup.select('.zentriert:nth-of-type(6):not([id])')]
    joined = [item.text for item in soup.select('.zentriert:nth-of-type(7):not([id])')]
    signed_from = ['/'.join([item.find('img')['title'].lstrip(': '), item.find('img')['alt']]) if item.find('a') else ''
                   for item in soup.select('.zentriert:nth-of-type(8):not([id])')]
    contract_until = [item.text for item in soup.select('.zentriert:nth-of-type(9):not([id])')]

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(position_number, position_description, name, dob, nationality, height, foot, joined, signed_from, contract_until)), columns = df_headers)
print(df)

df.to_csv(r'Uljanas-MacBook-Air-2:~ uljanadufour$\bayern-munich123.csv')
```

It would also be helpful to be able to differentiate between the webpages once scraped.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you append timestamp in your csv file to differentiate and avoid overlapping in each execution. `i.e "bayern-munich123_"+TS+".csv"` TS variable to hold today's date.

Comment: Others seem to have interpreted "without overwriting" as meaning that you don't want to overwrite your output CSV with another CSV. Judging by your code, your problem has more to do with the fact that each pandas' dataframe of scraped data is overwritten the by the succeeding dataframe as your program loops through `urls`. Can you clear up your intent for us?

Comment: Sorry about that. My intent is to generate a dataframe for each url (without being overwritten by the past one) in order to get an output CSV for each dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code above scrapes data for each URL, parses it *without* putting it in a dataframe, and then moves on to the next URL. Since your call to `pd.DataFrame()` occurs outside the loop, you are constructing a dataframe of page data from the very last URL in `urls`.

You need to create a dataframe outside of your for-loop, and then append incoming data for each URL to this dataframe.

```python
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import re
import pandas as pd
import itertools

headers = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0'}
df_headers = ['position_number' , 'position_description' , 'name' , 'dob' , 'nationality' , 'height' , 'foot' , 'joined' , 'signed_from' , 'contract_until']
urls = ['https://www.transfermarkt.com/fc-bayern-munich-u17/kader/verein/21058/saison_id/2018/plus/1', 'https://www.transfermarkt.com/fc-hennef-05-u17/kader/verein/48776/saison_id/2018/plus/1']

#### Add this before for-loop. ####
# Create empty dataframe with expected column names.
df_full = pd.DataFrame(columns = df_headers)

for url in urls:
    r = requests.get(url,  headers = headers)
    soup = bs(r.content, 'html.parser')


    position_number = [item.text for item in soup.select('.items .rn_nummer')]
    position_description = [item.text for item in soup.select('.items td:not([class])')]
    name = [item.text for item in soup.select('.hide-for-small .spielprofil_tooltip')]
    dob = [item.text for item in soup.select('.zentriert:nth-of-type(3):not([id])')]
    nationality = ['/'.join([i['title'] for i in item.select('[title]')]) for item in soup.select('.zentriert:nth-of-type(4):not([id])')]
    height = [item.text for item in soup.select('.zentriert:nth-of-type(5):not([id])')]
    foot = [item.text for item in soup.select('.zentriert:nth-of-type(6):not([id])')]
    joined = [item.text for item in soup.select('.zentriert:nth-of-type(7):not([id])')]
    signed_from = ['/'.join([item.find('img')['title'].lstrip(': '), item.find('img')['alt']]) if item.find('a') else ''
                   for item in soup.select('.zentriert:nth-of-type(8):not([id])')]
    contract_until = [item.text for item in soup.select('.zentriert:nth-of-type(9):not([id])')]


    #### Add this to for-loop. ####

    # Create a dataframe for page data.
    df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(position_number, position_description, name, dob, nationality, height, foot, joined, signed_from, contract_until)), columns = df_headers)

    # Add page URL to index of page data.
    df.index = [url] * len(df)

    # Append page data to full data.
    df_full = df_full.append(df)

print(df_full)
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, makes complete sense now.

Answer (score 0):

Two possible approaches:

1. You could add a timestamp to your filename so that you create a different CSV file for each time that your run your script

   ```
   from datetime import datetime

   timestamp = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H.%m.%s")
   df.to_csv(rf'Uljanas-MacBook-Air-2:~ uljanadufour$\{timestamp}  bayern-munich123.csv')
   ```

   Which would give you files in the format:

   ```
   "2019-05-08 10.39.05  bayern-munich123.csv"
   ```

   By using year month day format, your files will automatically be sorted chronologically.
2. Alternatively you could use the append mode to add to your existing CSV file:

   ```
   df.to_csv(r'Uljanas-MacBook-Air-2:~ uljanadufour$\bayern-munich123.csv', mode='a')
   ```

Finally, your current code is only saving the last URL, if you want to save each URL as a different file, you would need to indent your last two lines inside your loop. You could add a number to the filename to distinguish between each of the URLs, e.g. `1` or `2` as follows. Python's `enumerate()` function can be used to give you a number for each URL:

```
from datetime import datetime
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import re
import pandas as pd
import itertools


headers = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0'}
df_headers = ['position_number' , 'position_description' , 'name' , 'dob' , 'nationality' , 'height' , 'foot' , 'joined' , 'signed_from' , 'contract_until']

urls = [
    'https://www.transfermarkt.com/fc-bayern-munich-u17/kader/verein/21058/saison_id/2018/plus/1', 
    'https://www.transfermarkt.com/fc-hennef-05-u17/kader/verein/48776/saison_id/2018/plus/1'
]

for index, url in enumerate(urls, start=1):
    r = requests.get(url,  headers=headers)
    soup = bs(r.content, 'html.parser')

    position_number = [item.text for item in soup.select('.items .rn_nummer')]
    position_description = [item.text for item in soup.select('.items td:not([class])')]
    name = [item.text for item in soup.select('.hide-for-small .spielprofil_tooltip')]
    dob = [item.text for item in soup.select('.zentriert:nth-of-type(3):not([id])')]
    nationality = ['/'.join([i['title'] for i in item.select('[title]')]) for item in soup.select('.zentriert:nth-of-type(4):not([id])')]
    height = [item.text for item in soup.select('.zentriert:nth-of-type(5):not([id])')]
    foot = [item.text for item in soup.select('.zentriert:nth-of-type(6):not([id])')]
    joined = [item.text for item in soup.select('.zentriert:nth-of-type(7):not([id])')]
    signed_from = ['/'.join([item.find('img')['title'].lstrip(': '), item.find('img')['alt']]) if item.find('a') else ''
                   for item in soup.select('.zentriert:nth-of-type(8):not([id])')]
    contract_until = [item.text for item in soup.select('.zentriert:nth-of-type(9):not([id])')]

    df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(position_number, position_description, name, dob, nationality, height, foot, joined, signed_from, contract_until)), columns = df_headers)

    timestamp = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H.%M.%S")
    df.to_csv(rf'{timestamp}  bayern-munich123_{index}.csv')
```

This would then give you filesnames such as:

```
"2019-05-08 11.44.38  bayern-munich123_1.csv"
```